How to spin up only one docker container for tests in multiple projects when using TestContainers and Xunit
I have a few tests in multiple projects in one dotnet solution. I'm using TestContainers for managing the docker containers and Xunit as the testing tool. I want to initialize one Cassandra instance in docker, run all the tests and destroy it after the all tests are done.
Following code shows the current solution for spinning only one Cassandra instance.
public class EmptyContainerWrapper : ContainerWrapper
{
    public EmptyContainerWrapper ()
    {}
}

public class SharedContainerInstance
{
    private static readonly Lazy<EmptyContainerWrapper > _instance =
        new(() => new EmptyContainerWrapper ());

    public static EmptyContainerWrapper Instance => _instance.Value;

    // Optional: Method to dispose of the container, if needed
    public static void Dispose()
    {
        if (_instance.IsValueCreated)
        {
            _instance.Value.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

ContainerWrapper is responsible for container initialization, creating the relevant session objects that are needed for connecting to the cassandra database, resolving dependencies and destroying the container. And it is a protected class.
However SharedContainerInstance creates a static object of EmptyContainerWrapper, multiple cassandra instances were generated, when I run dotnet test command in the CMD. This causes overflowing the CPU capacity.
Following is an example way of how I use the static EmptyContainerWrapper for my tests.
public class MigrationTests
{
    private readonly EmptyContainerWrapper _wrapper;

    public MigrationTests()
    {
        _wrapper = SharedContainerInstance.Instance;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        var testRunId = await MigrationTestBase.CreateTestLogRows(_wrapper);
        //some code for testing purpose
    }

    ..........
}

Update:
I ran all the tests through the visual studio test explorer and through CLI. Both create containers per each project. So my solution only works for project level, not for solution level. Therefore I guess this situation relates to the parallel execution of the dotnet test command. Is there a way to run the test projects parallelly using the same container wrapper instance?
